# how to add a view over window in uiviewcontroller

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to add a subview over the window from a uiviewcontroller and then removing that also?

Thanks
Pankaj

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure what you mean...

```
[self.view addSubview:yoursubview];

[yoursubview removeFromSuperview];
```

Over the window:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:yourview];
```

Comment: by these lines the view is added over current view but i want add it over window. I am calling this method from a tableviewcontroller so it is adding new view(activity indicator view) over table only but i want to add it over the complete screen(including navigation and tab view controller.

Comment: @pankaj,Joseph Tura It works for me but in ipad landscape mode it always showing in portrait mode screen.. how to solve it.. my ipad app should run in landscap mode only.. how to solve in... [self.view.window addSubview:gall.view]; in viewcontroller but in gall view visible in Portrait mode, how to turn it into landscape mode.. any ideas..

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:yourView];
```

Comment: Provide a bit more info about the solution you're presenting please

Comment: @JoëlSalamin Joseph's solution, unfortunately, doesn't work for me. So you can choose all `windows` (NSArray), and than select `mainWindow` at index `0`

Answer (score 0):

[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.subviews.firstObject addSubview:yourView];

if you are using an iPad in landscape you should add your view over ther window's first subview.

@Yuvaraj.M this is the solution to your problem

Comment: It seems [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:yourview]; works on iPad in landscape mode as well. (ios8)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this too.

For adding:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController addChildViewController:childVC];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.view addSubview:childVC.view];
```

For removing:

```
[childVC.view removeFromSuperview];
[childVC removeFromParentViewController];
```