# Make AppDelegate's Navigation Controller accessible from DetailViewController of SplitView

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller, annotations, uisplitviewcontroller

My DetailView of a SplitView has a Map with Annotations. Upon clicking an Annotation the entire window (and not just the DetailView) should go to another view. Unfortunately that doesn't work.

This is how I'm creating my NavigationController in my AppDelegate

```
 UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];  
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

This is how I'm creating the SplitView

```
left = [[MapSplitViewLeft alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
right = [[MapViewController alloc] init];

splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:left,right, nil];

self.view = splitViewController.view;

left.right = right;

[left release];
[right release];
```

And that's what's being called when clicked on an Annotation:

```
- (void)showDetails:(id)sender {

 NSLog(@"Yes it works");

 VenueViewController *vviewcontroller = [[VenueViewController alloc]
 initWithNibName:@"VenueViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

 AppDelegate *del = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
 [del.navigationController pushViewController:vviewcontroller animated:YES];

}
```

When I click on the Annotation I only get "Yes it works" but nothing else is happening.
Thanks so much for any advise.

Answer (score 0):

Every UIViewController has the property "navigationController". Try with your current ViewController to push the new Viewcontroller.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vviewcontroller animated:YES];
```

edit: Sorry, you mean the entire window! I think that would not work.

edit2: Maybe this answer can help you [how to add a view over window in uiviewcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178196/how-to-add-a-view-over-window-in-uiviewcontroller) But i think thats that view is not on your navigationController-Stack

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using my split controller as the 2nd view in my app, and I just read somewhere that apple doesn't allow that, apparently it always has to be at the root of the app. Hence the difficulties to use the main navigation controller.