# How to place particular cell at the bottom of the table view?

Tags: ios, swift

I am having tableviewcontroller. In which I have defined 2 custom cells. One for user actions and another one for logout action. logout cell should appear at the bottom of the tableview.

Problem is, I have just 2 user actions. So, immediately after these 2 rows itself, logout cell is appearing.

How do I place this cell at the bottom of the tableview(screen)?

Comment: what about using table view footer?

Comment: use tableview footer

Comment: tried the same! But content of that footer I can see only when I scroll the table view.. I tried setting height for footer view also. Still it didn't work.

Comment: then set the one view above tablview

Comment: karthik, I am using uitableviewcontroller. we can't place any view on it I think so.

Comment: @ManjuJK - see this for example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577569/add-view-over-tableview-uitableviewcontroller

Comment: @Anbu.karthik I check it. but in my case I am using SWRevealViewController for getting menu screen. In library, sw_rear segue requires controller to be tableviewcontroller only.

Comment: @ManjuJK - simple change the frame

Comment: Tableview footer should be the best option. you shouldn't need to scroll if you only have two cells. you need to check your implementation

Comment: sorry @Anbu.karthik. I didn't get you. change frame of?

Comment: You have to add subview to Main View (over the tableview) If you want that view always on top,You have two options 1) Switch to UIViewController and add uitableview and logout buton 2) If you are using navigation controller then add subview to navigation controlller or add subview to Window

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya done with first option.. thank you. thank you everyone..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this in a viewcontroller.
design a logout button in the bottom of a viewcontroller and above that a tableview which you want with user action cell.

[this is how you can design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYSun.png)